# Setting Apache user and group dynamically

Tags: apache-2.2, users

In Apache Web Server, is there a way to set user and group differently between virtual hosts? I want to run PHP script with the owner's permission (in mod_php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the following:

- [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/) - run PHP as a user
- [suExec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) - run CGI as a user (if you run PHP as CGI)

These will run PHP as the user you specify in your VirtualHosts configuration.

Chances are your linux distro will already have these available in a repository somewhere.

- Ubuntu saucy has suPHP available in "universe".
- CentOS and Fedora don't have it in its normal repo, but it is available in RPMForge, for example: http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el6/x86_64/mod_suphp-0.7.1-1.el6.rf.x86_64.html

See http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/confusion-suphp-suphpexec-apache-suexec-117633.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use *apache2-mpm-itk* which allows to customize Apache *user* and *group* used for each *virtual host*.

*apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk*

*nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/mydomain.com
    Options -Indexes
    AssignUserID myuser mygroup
</VirtualHost>
```

See [Create and set up an Apache virtual host](http://en.open-lamp.com/create-and-set-up-an-apache-virtual-host/) for more details.

Comment: You have spared me of using ACL's. For the moment :-)